# .htaccess: set request as allowed when rewrited

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure this must have been asked many times but I can't find anything about this on internet or in the doc.
I want to deny everything except some requests that are rewrited using RewriteRule.

Currently I'm using this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^req$ file.php?a=b
<Files *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
<Files file.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

I would have liked this .htaccess to allow all requests to file.php, including *req* as it's rewrited to it.
Instead, it won't allow *req* except if I explicitly mention *req* in the allowed files:

```
<Files req>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour, something like the opposite of the F flag?

Comment: not really possible. mod_rewrite just mangles urls. it isn't aware of any other restrictions/modifications performed by other parts of apache. if you rewrite to a url that is blocked by some other config option in apache's setup, that isn't the rewrite's problem.

Comment: what you COULD do is have modrewrite set an env var when you do rewrite to this "forbidden" script, then check for that var when blocking access elsewhere in apache. if the env var exists, then allow the request.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in the OP or I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting but I'm not trying to deny access to file.php, what I want is to allow access to _req_ **without** having to write the "Files req" entry

Comment: and that's what I'm suggesting. rewrite and files are two DIFFERENT areas of apache, and they don't communicate. if you want files to allow that particular url, then you have to tell apache that. e.g. rewrite sets the env var, files disallows access UNLESS that env var is present. or you leave it as is and have the two files definitions.

Comment: I see now, thank you I'll try that